# Parsing strange JSON-like format

Tags: json, parsing, google-vision, dataformat

I got some strange JSON-like format from Google Cloud OCR. It doesn't have quoted keys, colons, or commas.

```
text_annotations {
  description: ","
  bounding_poly {
    vertices {
      x: 485
      y: 237
    }
    vertices {
      x: 492
      y: 237
    }
    vertices {
      x: 492
      y: 266
    }
    vertices {
      x: 485
      y: 266
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any simple way to parse it, or format as JSON?

I've tried adding quotes, colons, and commas by hand, but it's not the best way.

Got these data using python code:

```
from google.cloud import vision
import io
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

feature = vision.Feature(
    type_=vision.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)


with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)

response = client.text_detection(image=image)
print(response)
```

Comment: Precisely what did you do in order to receive that response? (PLEASE do not include your authentication keys when answering that question. Also, answer it by editing your question, not replying to this comment. Thanks.)

Comment: I got it by 
 client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient() 
 response =client.text_detection(image=image)
 print(response)

Comment: OK. My guess is that the response you received is already parsed. Printing it produces some text string which the developers thought would be useful for viewing, but it should not be used for parsing (since the response is already parsed).

Comment: So is there any way to get it from google in proper JSON format?

Comment: The attributes of the annotaion object seem to be documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/vision/latest/google.cloud.vision_v1.types.EntityAnnotation). Or at least, that might be a reasonable place to start experimenting.

Comment: As for converting it back to JSON (why?), I don't know. If you can convert it to a Python dict, you could use Python's JSON module to do the conversion; perhaps that will just work (if the developers set up the annotation object in a way that permits it).

Comment: My target is to convert it to Python dict in the easiest way, got many files with this format, and want to extract data from it, but in its present form is unusable, i thought about trying to add missing chars programmaticaly to make it JSON compatible, then read it by python script.

Comment: I'm sure it's quite usable. But the way to use it is not to try to reparse the result of calling `str` on it. That will just lead to madness. Figure out how to get its attributes. (Likely `response.text_annotations`), and work from there. The `dir` function is a good way of inspecting the attributes of a Python object.

Comment: Perhaps the response is a protobuf. If that's the case, https://pypi.org/project/protobuf-to-dict/ (or similar) might prove useful.

Comment: Actually, i got saved output of many OCRd pics, and don't want to use more quota. i will look on this protobuf suggestion later, now i g2g, thanks for help :)

Comment: I strongly suggest you take @rici's second comment regarding the return object seriously. The classes are well documented. For example see [AnnotateImageResponse](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/vision/latest/google.cloud.vision_v1.types.AnnotateImageResponse).  Use the API to navigate the objects and convert the values to whatever you please.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i just did as people proposed in comments, and used API to print data in more useful format.

Answer (score -1):

OK, making a custom parser is probably overkill, but what about this potentially easy, quick&dirty hack: if the linebreaks and indentation etc. are stable, could you do a search + replace on these (via a tool, because then can be automated and also perform multiple replacements) in the form of replacing "`\n  bounding_poly`" with "`,\n  "bounding_poly": [`", which adds the comma to the previous line, adds the colon to the key, adds quotes to the key, turns its contents into an array (you then too get rid of the `"vertices"` so they become anonymous objects inside the array as the array's elements). Please be aware of newline encoding differences (`\n`, `\r\n`, `\r`).

Ideally also recognize if one of these search strings matches zero times, or attempt to read the final result as JSON to check for error messages.

Not great, but maybe sufficient? Or has the source more variance or is it more dynamic/unstable?